# appium android setup on mac 10.8.5

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, appium

Based on some reference links, I have setup the environment as below.

```
# ~/.bash_profile
export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/adt/adt-bundle-mac-x86_64-20140702/android-sdks
export ANDROID_SDK=$ANDROID_HOME
PATH=$PATH:/Users/sathiyarengarajan/Documents/Eclipse SetUp/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin
PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/npm
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export JAVA_HOME=`/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/A/Commands/java_home`
export PATH
```

If I try to lauch Appium, is says **/Users/sathiyarengarajan/.bash_profile: line 15: .bash_profile: No such file or directory**.

Please let me know if I am missing anything in the setup. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where did you open your bash_profile in to. It should be done as

touch ~/.bash_profile

open ~/.bash_profile (after it is opened you insert your exports inside and after that you close it) and source ~/.bash_profile(source because you need the changes to take effect right now)